# for loop with a list ... entities with spaces

Tags: shell-script, for

As a intermediate step I want to produce one line per string in '' with below script

```
#!/usr/bin/env/ bash

TOMCAT_OFF=('16:00 19.01.2023' '16:00 21.02.2023' '16:00 15.02.2023')

for i in ${TOMCAT_OFF[@]}
do
    echo "${i}"
done
```

I am getting one line for time + one line for date though (so total 6 instead of 3). I tried various delimiters ('', "", ``) as well as throwing in an escape \ prior the devisive space (like `'16:00\ 01.01.2023'`).

Nothing worked thus far though. How can I have bash to interpret a string with spaces as one entity of that list?

Comment: You need `"${TOMCAT_OFF[@]}"`, with the quotes to prevent wordsplitting and globbing, and to get the array elements intact. (The quotes don't tie all the values together here, arrays with `[@]` are an exception.) Don't put quotes inside your data, they're syntax elements, and trying to mix those with data is almost always a mistake.

Comment: `for i in "${TOMCAT_OFF[@]}"` to be precise (you left the `$` out)

Comment: Still had time to edit! But yeah, mistyped that, sorry